# Entendendo o Node e Aplicações em tempo real

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, node.js

Desde que conheci o [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) me acostumei a programar com ele, pois tinha uma curva de aprendizado pequena e agilizava muito o desenvolvimento.

Para a minha recente aplicação, precisava que os dados inseridos pelos usuários fossem monitorados em tempo real em relação a sua quantidade (um simples `COUNT` no mysql). Pesquisando sobre o assunto, encontrei o NodeJS.

Agora estou começando a entender o NodeJS e sua aplicação mas não sei se entendi direito mas ao que me parece, se eu quiser fazer uma aplicação em tempo real ou parte dela, eu tenho que "jogar fora" tudo que aprendi e fazer tudo novamente no NodeJS?
Eu queria só monitorar a inserção de dados em tempo real, mas parece que isso não é possivel pois o NodeJS substituiria o Apache e talvez até o PHP utilizando módulos que se conectam ao MySQL.

Tudo que encontro é em inglês e, a pouca parte em português, é praticamente uma tradução dos textos em inglês
Então eis algumas perguntas que pra mim, não ficaram claras:

- O NodeJS substitui o Apache e tenho que escolher entre um e outro?
- O NodeJS substitui o PHP? Por exemplo quando pelo proprio node temos a conexão com Mysql?
- Não é possível a integração do Node com o Cakephp ou outro framework, tipo Rails?
- Se eu tiver uma aplicação já pronta e quiser integra-la no NodeJS, tenho que reescreve-la?
- O NodeJS depende do Nginx? Se não, usar os 2 ao mesmo tempo é uma boa saída?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Já trabalhei muitos anos com PHP, hoje trabalho muito com Python, NodeJS e nginx. Tenho um ponto de vista um pouco diferente dos até agora apresentados.

**O Node substitui o Apache e tenho que escolher entre um e outro?**

Você pode utilizar o node pra ser o servidor também, mas não é uma boa prática, é possível integrar o node pra trabalhar com outros servidores, inclusive Apache.

**O Node substitui o php? Por exemplo quando pelo proprio node temos a conexão com Mysql?**

Node pode substituir o PHP sim, pode se conectar com MySQL e outras bases de dados, tal qual o PHP, depende o objetivo da sua aplicação e da estratégia que quer adotar o Node pode ser uma solução mais adequada que o PHP.

**Não é possível a integração do Node com o Cakephp ou outro framework, tipo Rails?**

Você não vai conseguir escrever um arquivo com PHP e Javascript e processar nos dois ao mesmo tempo, mas integra-los é possível sim, tanto o PHP fazer requisições para o servidor node quanto o contrário. Também é possível com Rails ou Python. Hoje utilizamos na empresa onde trabalho um servidor de middleware feito em Python com Django integrado com servidores distribuidos de Node que fazem a parte de comunicação em websocket assincronoma.

**Se eu tiver uma aplicação já pronta e quiser integra-la no Node, tenho que reescreve-la?**

Depende o que você quer integrar, mas provavelmente precisara de alterações nos pontos de integração para funcionar com as novas dependências.

**O Node depende do Nginx? Se não, usar os 2 ao mesmo tempo é uma boa saída?**

Não é dependente, mas o nginx é um ótimo servidor para se trabalhar com o Node, seja para fazer parte de cache ou mesmo para trabalhar com multiplos upstream de nodejs, permitindo balanceamento de carga nos seus servidores.

Uma das coisas que você pode fazer para integrar seus sistemas é ter o servidor de nginx dando acesso externo e mapeando os paths que vão cair no nodejs e os que vão cair no seu apache que fornece o PHP (caso use recursos do Apache integrado ao seu PHP, caso contrário, pode usar o nginx para acessar diretamente seu PHP também).

Então no caso de monitorar um `COUNT` em tempo real, uma das aplicações interessantes, seria um servidor de websocket em nodejs, onde os seus usuários poderiam estar conectados e trafegando dados em tempo real. No lado do servidor seu PHP poderia avisar ao seu Node toda vez que ele fizesse uma operação de inserção ou remoção na base de dados, de forma que o node replicasse o valor de `COUNT` para seus clientes em tempo real.

Toda essa operação é possível com PHP também, utilizando Pushstream, porém no fim das contas é tão mais complicado, que vale a pena adotar o node para uma solução desse tipo. Até mesmo chat ou jogos são legais pra se trabalhar com node, pois a proposta dele é tudo ser tratado como eventos em micro blocos e não como arquivos processados como blocos e enviados para o cliente igual o PHP.

Comment: vc poderia me indicar um texto ou site onde eu possa ver um exemplo de count como esse que vc mencionou acima?

Comment: Bom uma das maneiras que eu costumo comunicar entre diferentes linguagens é utilizando protocolo HTTP (pois é bem simples e a maioria suporta). Da uma olhada nesse site: http://resthooks.org/ o conceito de hooks se aplica a qualquer layer de comunicação seja entre aplicações ou cliente. Mas como para o cliente você não tem como transformar o browser em um servidor HTTP que espera por uma requisição, a gente usa websocket ou longpooling pra fazer requisição do servidor para o cliente quando o hook no servidor é disparado por outra aplicação interna. Não tenho projetos opensource pra demonstrar.

Answer (score 6):

> O Node substitui o Apache e tenho que escolher entre um e outro?

O [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) possui um webserver próprio, mas é compatível com Apache, Lighttpd, Nginx e outros.

Para fazê-lo rodar sobre o Apache, aqui tem um [tutorial](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache).

> O Node substitui o php? Por exemplo quando pelo próprio node temos a conexão com Mysql?

Sim, o Node é uma plataforma server-side que faz mais ou menos o mesmo papel do PHP.

> Não é possível a integração do Node com o Cakephp ou outro framework, tipo rayls?

Não é possível, pois Cake é escrito em PHP e o Rails em Ruby. O Node tem seu próprio ecossistema. Exitem vários frameworks para ele, como o [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/)

> Se eu tiver uma aplicação já pronta e quiser integra-la no Node, tenho que reescreve-la?

Depende de como você vai fazer a integração.

> O Node depende do Nginx? Se não, usar os 2 ao mesmo tempo é uma boa saída?

São coisas distintas, para propósitos diferentes. O Node é a linguagem, o Nginx é o servidor web.

Comment: `o Node é uma linguagem server-side` Na verdade a linguagem é Javascript. De resto, +1.

Comment: @Renan A afirmação acima está correta porquê o Node roda no servidor, por mais que seja javascript.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck **Node.js** (que é a forma de escrever o nome da tecnologia) não é uma linguagem.

Comment: @Renan desculpe, agora entendi o que você quis dizer. De fato o Node.js não é uma linguagem.

Comment: Há controvérsias. Embora ele use um motor Javascript (o V8), existem coisas que diferenciam o Node do JS do browser. Eu acabo por considerá-lo uma outra linguagem.

Answer (score 4):

**1. O Node substitui o Apache e tenho que escolher entre um e outro?**

Sim, mas não é mandatório. Ele pode ser executado juntamente com o Apache, basta que esteja ouvindo uma porta diferente.

**2. O Node substitui o php? Por exemplo quando pelo proprio node temos a conexão com Mysql?**

Conforme a resposta da primeira pergunta, não. Eles podem co-existir sem problemas

**3. Não é possível a integração do Node com o Cakephp ou outro framework, tipo rayls?**

Eu não sou safo com PHP, mas o Node é capaz de responder a qualquer tipo de requisição. Então você básicamente precisaria implementar um serviço que ouvisse determinada porta e atendesse suas requisições PHP. Seriam requisições HTTP normais (GET, POST, etc...).

**4. Se eu tiver uma aplicação já pronta e quiser integra-la no Node, tenho que reescreve-la?**

Não seria necessário, mas você teria que avaliar como seria feita a integração.

**5. O Node depende do Nginx? Se não, usar os 2 ao mesmo tempo é uma boa saída?**

Infelizmente eu não sei te dizer se o node depende do Nginix pois nunca pesquisei a respeito. O que posso lhe afirmar é que ele, o Nginix, é um servidor muito leve, inclusive consome até menos memória que o Apache. Não teria problemas utilizar os dois ao mesmo tempo.

Caso eu encontre algo sobre o assunto eu edito minha resposta.

Apenas para enriquecer sua experiência com o Node, deixarei este [link](https://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/) com algumas extensões que vão lhe ajudar muito.

Comment: Também não sei muito sobre isso, mas já ouvi falar no uso do Nginx na frente do Node para lidar com cache.

Answer (score 0):

> Não é possível a integração do Node com o Cakephp ou outro framework, tipo rayls?

É totalmente possível utilizar o CakePhp com o Node.
Recentemente implementei um sistema de notificações e um chat (ambos realtime) entre dois users (utilizando o NodeJs) em um sistema feito em CakePhp.
Uso o CakePhp para gravar mensagens e notificações no DB e o Node para notificar em realtime.